# Cannot plot a function that calls Eigensystem on a large matrix

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, evaluation

Is there a way to plot an expensive function without resorting to making a list of values and using `ListPlot`?

I have a function called `gap[h,size]` which computes the difference between the lowest two eigenvalues in a large sparse matrix. `h` is a parameter in the matrix that varies from 0 to 1 while `size` controls the size of the matrix. The matrix contains `2^size * 2^size` entries.

Computing `gap[h,size]` gets expensive as `size` gets larger, but it's reasonable to get all the way up to `size=18` at which point each evaluation takes around 8 seconds.

Here is my problem: Although I can compute a list of values of `gap[h,18]` at different values of `h`, I cannot plot the function `gap[h,18]` at all. Even at a more modest value of `size=12`,

```
Plot[
    gap[h, 12],
    {h, 0, 1},
    PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 0
 ]
```

will not run, even though computing

```
Table[gap[h, 12], {h, 0, 1, 0.1}]
```

takes only half a second. During evaluation Mathematica runs a single CPU core at 100% but doesn't hog any memory.

Here is some sample code to try for yourself. The matrix is already diagonal, but you cannot plot `gap` for values above `size=10`.

```
largeMatrix[h_, size_] :=
    SparseArray[            
            {i_, i_} -> h,
            {2^size, 2^size}
                ]
sparseIdentity[length_] := 
  SparseArray[{i_, i_} -> 1, {2^length, 2^length}];
sparseEigensystem[matrix_, length_, valuesKept_] := 
 Block[{values, vectors},
    {values, vectors} = 
   Eigensystem[matrix - length*sparseIdentity[length], valuesKept];
    {values + length, vectors}
    ]
ClearAll[gap]
gap[h_, length_] /; NumericQ[h] := 
 gap[h, length] = Block[{values, vectors},
    {values, vectors} = 
    sparseEigensystem[largeMatrix[h, length], length, 2];
    EuclideanDistance @@ values
   ]
```

Comment: By "will not run" do you mean "doesn't terminate in the time I've waited"?

Comment: You could try Chebyshev interpolation. There's ``Statistics`Library`BarycentricInterpolation`` to help with this.  Search the site or see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191070/complex-continuation-of-an-interpolated-function/191600#191600

Comment: Try wrapping your `Plot` with `Monitor` to see where it gets stuck.

Comment: Have you tried using `Evaluate`? `Plot[Evaluate@gap[h, 12], ...]`

Comment: Thanks everyone, these are useful suggestions and I will try them. Sorry to not put the matrix in the question, but it's too big of course.

Comment: @lericr yes. The plot with those options should only query 10 points, and it only takes about 0.5 seconds to compute those 10 points in a `Table`.

Comment: @BobHanlon I have tried `Evaluate`, it does not do anything.

Comment: @ChrisK I'm not exactly sure how to use Monitor. I tried `Monitor[Plot[
   (debug = h; Evaluate@gap[h, 12]),
   {h, 0, 1},
   PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 0,
   PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
  ], debug]` which just printed `debug` and nothing more.

Comment: @Diffycue Try `Monitor[Plot[gap[h, 12], {h, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 0], h]`.  Another thought: you could try using `_?NumericQ` in your definition of `gap`. Try `Clear[gap]; gap[h_?NumericQ, size_Integer] := ... your definition`.

Comment: @ChrisK I think this problem is harder than I anticipated at first. I'll update the question with some example code that presents the same problem.

Comment: `Table[gap[h, 16], {h, 0, 1, 0.1}]` is all `0.0`s.  Is that right?

Comment: @ChrisK That's right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I ran

```
Monitor[Plot[gap[h, 16], {h, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 0], h]
```

I noticed it got stuck on `0`.  Avoiding integers fixes it:

```
Plot[gap[h, 16], {h, 0., 1.}, PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

runs in 0.08s.